# Take elements from each group in Polars

Tags: python-polars

How can I take elements by index within each group of a Polars `DataFrame`? For example, if I wanted to get the first and third element of each group, I might try something like this:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(dict(x=[1,0,1,0,1,0], y=[1,2,3,4,5,6]))

df.groupby('x').take([0,2])
# AttributeError: 'GroupBy' object has no attribute 'take'
```

But that does not work, obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
df.groupby("x").agg(pl.all().take([0, 2]))
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬────────────┐
│ x   ┆ y          │
│ --- ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ list [i64] │
╞═════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ [1, 5]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ [2, 6]     │
└─────┴────────────┘
```

You can use `explode` to flatten the list column if needed.

```py
df.groupby("x").agg(pl.all().take([0, 2])).explode('y')
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ x   ┆ y   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ 2   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

The documentation for the `take` expression has a similar [example](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.take.html).